# Hide bottom status bar in SSMS

Tags: ssms

Is there a way to hide the most bottom status bar? It doesn't have that much useful information (line number, column number, etc) and takes a decent amount of screen real-estate. I don't think it's hideable but I figured I'd ask.

See image below
[image]

SSMS 17.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On v18.5
Tools->Options->Environment->General->Uncheck Display status bar

Comment: Thanks @Flou! I see this option on SSMS 17.6 also.